# GraphicsMagic is unable to identify background transparency of PDF

Tags: pdf, png, ghostscript, graphicsmagick

GM is unable to identify background transparency of PDF and PNG created using "gm convert" gets white background while same PDF is converted to PNG with transparent background by IM.

```
$convert -verbose /var/tmp/abc.pdf /var/tmp/abc.png
```

```
/var/tmp/magick-16370Tq7WYv5U54Pa1 PNG 288x720 288x720+0+0 8-bit sRGB 20.7KB 0.000u 0:00.009
/var/tmp/abc.pdf PDF 288x720 288x720+0+0 16-bit sRGB 20.7KB 0.000u 0:00.000
/var/tmp/abc.pdf=>/var/tmp/abc.png PDF 288x720 288x720+0+0 8-bit sRGB 17c 16.6KB 0.010u 0:00.009
[ghostscript library] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72" "-sOutputFile=/var/tmp/magick-16370Tq7WYv5U54Pa%d" "-f/var/tmp/magick-16370CVWmPbzBmjpF" "-f/var/tmp/magick-16370khy6Y-G3TgtO"
```

```
$gm convert -verbose /var/tmp/abc.pdf /var/tmp/abc.png
```

```
gm convert: "gs" "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" "-dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=pnmraw" "-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4" "-r72x72" "-sOutputFile=/var/folders/6d/n_hv45rs1jv17nxwfjwj776cspn_3c/T/gmoCp6rG" "--" "/var/folders/6d/n_hv45rs1jv17nxwfjwj776cspn_3c/T/gmBEgWnK" "-c" "quit".
/var/tmp/abc.pdf PDF 288x720+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 607.6K 0.000u 0:01
/var/tmp/abc.pdf=>/var/tmp/abc.png PNG 288x720+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 0.000u 0:01
Upon further investigation, it seems "identify" from IM can correctly identify background in PDF but "gm identify" from GM cannot.
```

```
$identify -verbose abc.pdf
```

```
Image: abc.pdf
Format: PDF (Portable Document Format)
Type: Bilevel
Colorspace: Gray
Depth: 16/4-bit
Channel depth:
gray: 1-bit
alpha: 4-bit
Alpha: graya(255,0) #FFFFFFFFFFFF0000
Colors: 16
Background color: graya(255,1)
Transparent color: graya(0,0)
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-1 Q16 x86_64 2014-07-01 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

```
$gm identify -verbose abc.pdf
```

```
gm identify: "gs" "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" "-dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=pnmraw" "-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4" "-r72x72" "-sOutputFile=/var/folders/6d/n_hv45rs1jv17nxwfjwj776cspn_3c/T/gmzhBEIk" "--" "/var/folders/6d/n_hv45rs1jv17nxwfjwj776cspn_3c/T/gmAPm2Po" "-c" "quit".
Image: abc.pdf
Format: PDF (Portable Document Format)
Type: grayscale
Depth: 4 bits-per-pixel component
Channel Depths:
Gray: 4 bits
Background Color: white
Comment: Image generated by GPL Ghostscript (device=pnmraw)
Signature: 215f1c08ec575526ce398d193c4df22faaea100c10255e0db747641bdaaeac49
Tainted: False
```

Comment: link to sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/discussion/250738/thread/8643b1af/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your (ImageMagick) `convert` and your (GraphicsMagick) `gm convert` commands produce different output is this:

1. Both utilities are ***NOT*** able to process PDF input files directly, both can only handle rater image formats.
2. In order to process PDF input files, both utilities resort to a *'delegate'* program: in both cases this is Ghostscript (which ***CAN*** process PDF input files).
3. Both utilities however do use ***different*** *'delegate command lines'* (as can be directly seen in your quoted `-verbose` commandline outputs:

   i. `convert` employs as its Ghostscript output device `pngalpha`.

   ii. `gm convert`employs as its Ghostscript output device `pnmraw`.
4. Both utilities then process the output of their delegate's command into the final (raster) format file.

The problem is: the raster format *'pnmraw'*  does not support transparency (an alpha channel), but *'pngalpha'* does. Hence, the utility which first converts PDF input to pnmraw has lost the transparent page backgrounds and replaced them by (opaque) white backgrounds.

***Unless you modify your GraphicsMagick setup to make it use `pngalpha` in its delegate command (the same as ImageMagick uses) your `gm convert` will not show transparent background.***

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add to [Kurt Pfeifle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359307/kurt-pfeifle) answer since it pointed me to this solution. The configuration that he is referring to is found in the **delegates.mgk** file (graphicsmagick/1.3.19_1/lib/GraphicsMagick/config).

For me the issue was this line:

```
<!-- Read color Postscript, EPS, and PDF  -->
<delegate decode="gs-color" stealth="True" command='"gs" -q -dBATCH -dMaxBitmap=50000000 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=ppmraw -dTextAlphaBits=%u -dGraphicsAlphaBits=%u -r%s %s "-sOutputFile=%s" -- "%s" -c quit' />
```

I changed it to:

```
  <delegate decode="gs-color+alpha" stealth="True" command='"gs" -q -dBATCH -dMaxBitmap=50000000 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dTextAlphaBits=%u -dGraphicsAlphaBits=%u -r%s %s "-sOutputFile=%s" -- "%s" -c quit' />
```

and my pngs come out with transparent backgrounds!